# Are Spark Streaming, Structured Streaming and Kafka Streaming the same thing?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-kafka-streams, spark-structured-streaming

I have come across three popular streaming techniques that are Spark Streaming, Structured Streaming and Kafka Streaming.
I have gone through various sites but not getting this answer, are these three the same thing or different?
If not same what is the basic difference.
I am not looking for an in depth  answer. But an answer to above question (yes or no) and a little intro to each of them so that I can explore more. :)

Thanks in advance
Subrat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are referring to `Kafka Streams` when you say "Kafka Streaming".

`Kafka Streams` is a JVM library, part of Apache Kafka. It is a way of processing data in Kafka topics providing an abstraction layer. Applications running `KafkaStreams` library can be run anywhere (not just in the Kafka cluster, actually, it is not recommended to). They'll consume, process and produce data to/from the Kafka cluster.

`Spark Streaming` is a part of Apache Spark distributed data processing library,  that provides Stream (as oppposed to batch) processing. Spark initially provided batch computation only, so a specific layer `Spark Streaming` was provided for stream processing. Spark Streaming can be fed with Kafka data, but it can be connected to other sources as well.

`Structured Streaming`, within the realm of Apache Spark, is a different approach that came to overcome certain limitations to stream processing of the previous approach that Spark Streaming was using. It was added to Spark from a certain version onwards(2.0 IIRC).

Comment: Thank you. That answered my query. :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that @SubratKP. In that case, please kindly accept my answer. Thanks!